# Prevent multiple form submission on hitting enter twice

Tags: laravel

When I'm trying to submit form, then I accidentally hit enter twice on submit button. In that case my form is submitted twice. Can any one advice me how I can handle this.

Here is the output which I needed:-

- form values must be submitted once
- even if user hit enter twice..

Comment: if you are using javascript or jquery you can prevent submit by disabling after hitting it for the first time

Comment: you can use use $(selector).dblclick()  jquery method to prevent single click page submission.

Comment: Yes.. as suggested either you can add restriction as javascript end also you can add unique validation on any field at laravel end to prevent this.

Comment: I've done it so well by Lakhwinder Singh suggestion.. but thank you so much i really do appreciate your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by jquery. Below is the same code.

In this example it will disable submit button for 2 seconds. After 2 seconds button will enable again. You can modify this according to your requirement.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $(this).find(':submit').attr( 'disabled','disabled' );
     //the rest of your code
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).find(':submit').attr( 'disabled',false );
    }, 2000)
});
```

Try this and let me know if you have any concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique property on a certain column on your database or validate it through Laravel [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

Comment: I've done it so well by Lakhwinder Singh suggestion.. but thank you so much i really do appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with disable the submit button for multiple clicks.

```
  $(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {

        $($(this)).prop('disabled', true);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by jquery

In this example, it will disable submit button for 2 seconds. After 2 seconds button will enable again. You can modify this according to your requirement.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $(this).find(':submit').attr( 'disabled','disabled' );
     //the rest of your code
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).find(':submit').attr( 'disabled',false );
    }, 2000)
});
```

Let me know if it works.